# calling builtin AI algorithms to train and predict via REST API

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, built-in

I saw few references to uploading saved models to Google cloud and using them via REST API. Is there any way we can utilize prebuilt(built-in) Google AI algorithm such as 'wide and deep' in web application. We have a case where we are working on self service application where users will upload datasets which needs to be provided to this algorithm for training. Once it has been trained, we would like to intimate user about availability of the trained model and use it via API calls for predicting. We know the saved custom model path and tried all ok. But we need to use builtin algorithm in similar fasion.

Any pointers are highly appreciated.
Kiran